# How to create checkbox validation

Tags: javascript

[image: screenshot]

I have a quantity field with the data quantity order and invoice quantity. I want to make checkbox validation using JavaScript with the following conditions:

1. If the quantity order quantity invoice checkbox = checked (ready to deliver and pending to deliver next) with readonly field quantity invoice.
2. If the order quantity <= quantity invoice checkbox is checked (Delivered Quantity Change and Change Item Order) with editable field quantity invoice.

```
<div class='panel' ".$warna.">
<div class='panel-body'>
<div class='form-group'>
<label style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>Quantity Order</label>
<p style='margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px;'>
    <b>".$qtyorder."</b></p><br />
<label style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>Quantity Invoice</label>
<input type='text' readonly='readonly' name='quantity' value=".$qty_invoice.">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample of all relevant code?

Comment: I have not made a javascript code because I'm confused, can you give me a hint to create java script to the problem as above

Comment: I don't see the  checkbox you are referring to in the code you have supplied